# Is there any way to append the variable in big query select in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, google-bigquery

I am trying to call the variable in a select query like below:

BEGIN

DECLARE TGT_LOAD_STATUS_TBL STRING;

SET TGT_LOAD_STATUS_TBL='`'||PROJ_ID||'.'||TGT_SCHEMA||'.'||LOAD_STATUS_TBL||'`';

FOR FETCH_TEST IN (select col1 from **TGT_LOAD_STATUS_TBL** WHERE LOAD_STATUS='N')
DO
INSERT INTO project.datasetid.table VALUES(FETCH_TEST.col1);
END FOR;

END

Is there any way to append the variable in a select query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use build your SQL statement by concatenating some strings together and then execute it using [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate). This is exactly the use case that EXECUTE IMMEDIATE exists for

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good practice to update a table one by one within a loop.
Instead consider a bulk update using a dynamic sql like below

```sql
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  INSERT INTO table1
  SELECT col1 FROM `%s` WHERE LOAD_STATUS='N'
""", TGT_LOAD_STATUS_TBL);
```

**Test Query:**

```sql
DECLARE TGT_LOAD_STATUS_TBL DEFAULT 'table2';

CREATE TEMP TABLE table1 (col1 STRING);
CREATE TEMP TABLE table2 AS
SELECT 'a' col1, 'N' LOAD_STATUS UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 'Y' UNION ALL
SELECT 'c', 'N' UNION ALL
SELECT 'd', 'N' UNION ALL
SELECT 'e', 'N' ;


EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  INSERT INTO table1
  SELECT col1 FROM `%s` WHERE LOAD_STATUS='N'
""", TGT_LOAD_STATUS_TBL);

SELECT * FROM table1;
```

[image]